Difference between a server running locally (on premises) with a cloud one
I was hearing someone talking about the cloud and how it is becoming more and more prevalent across companies and mentioned that most of the servers nowadays are made for the cloud and because of that if a company does not want to be in the cloud finding a server that is for local install/usage will become harder.
What does it mean that servers are made for the cloud? Isn't cloud servers either "regular" off the self physical servers or VMs installed on such regular servers?
Is there some difference between a server a company orders that its IT will maintain vs a server made to go to the cloud? Is there different hardware specs or something else?

The hyperscalers generally don’t buy regular off the shelf pizza box style servers, they deploy whole racks (or larger units) of more custom configured hardware. Their scale and specific use cases allow them to design exactly what they need and that fits exactly in their custom datacenters and there they can optimize and omit everything they won’t need.
Regular servers generally need to support options for a much wider variety of use cases , offer for example expansion slots for optional NIC cards for a variety of network speeds and (legacy) technologies, different local storage, HBA’s etc.
The market for those servers is not disappearing. That market is actually still growing. Many companies still have their own (on-premise) hardware to support business processes that they can’t or won’t run in the cloud, or which they can run cheaper themselves.
When you look at for example the revenue breakdown for a large server hardware provider like Dell https://www.statista.com/statistics/1122924/dell-revenue-by-subsegment/ you can see the combined revenue for servers and storage is still growing.
But that revenue and growth is smaller than cloud spending  by a really large margin.
https://www.idc.com/getdoc.jsp?containerId=prUS52343224

I see, so basically they order custom servers and I guess it would need companies such as Dell, to stop accepting orders for custom servers and only get orders from cloud providers? What is the difference between a hyper-scaler company that is running servers on-premise vs AWS or Google when it comes to submitting an order to Dell for new servers?

In regards to the revenue difference I was wondering if a job decline on IT support/SREs for on-premise hardware is also visible?
